# Boost classes for console shell

Tags: c++, shell, boost, command-line, console

Are there any classes in boost for implementing shell-like input in my console application. I've made my own application using boost::program_options but I don't like it. Is there some shell-specific solution?

Update 1:
found http://wanderinghorse.net/computing/shellish/eshell.html but it's only for unix. :(

Comment: A GNU library: http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Comment: Any chance for non-GPL library?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a happy user of [TinyCon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinycon/files/).

It's very light and easy to set-up. It works with Windows / Linux / OS X and it's BSD-licensed.

It's very minimalist, so I don't know if it's enough for your requirements.

Also, given that you are already using `boost::program_options`, you could take a look at [clipo](http://code.google.com/p/clipo/) (LGPL but the author may may authorize you to use the code under a different licence). The idea was to build a command line shell on top of the program_option library. Unfortunately the project isn't maintained anymore.

Anyway TinyCon and Clipo are quite simple and you could combine them (something I'm trying to do).

Comment: I have had something similar to TinyCon before I rewrote it using boost::program_options. So, still looking...

Comment: Clipo is not maintain but is working fine. Regarding the license, why LGPL is a problem. It is less restrictive than GPL if I'm right.